# How to redirect to www.domain.com in linux?

Tags: redirect

How di I redirect to www.domain.com when a user access a file in a server without www. ?

I am not just talking about index.php file.

THanks!

Comment: You might want to tell us which webserver you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

gruber uses the .htaccess to redirect. read more http://daringfireball.net/2006/05/htaccess_redirection

you could do the inverse.